# Alternatives to SQLite Manager, with WAL support?

Tags: sqlite

What application clients are there that can connect SQLite3 databases that have Write-Ahead Logging(WAL) are out there?  I am not finding one with my google foo today, I have the SQLite Manager Firefox extension.  Again I am not finding where it says that it has wal support for it however?  Can someone point me in the right direction please?

If I where to guess, I would say that as long as the client can open the SQLite3 file with wal, that the client supports wal.  However that is just a guess on my part.

#### EDIT 8/31/2012

As much as I don't like answering my own questions :p  So I am turning this into a, "what alternatives are there" question

Yes, there is a Client application that connects SQLite3 databases, it is a FireFox extension called SQLite Manager.  They added support for it apparently in [Apr 24, 2011 (or sometime there abouts)](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/issues/detail?id=602&can=1&q=WAL) according to their issue tracker.  For those of you who where wondering, there is the answer.  I needed this for work, wound up using the manager without knowing and figured I would take the time after to do a little more research.  I still have not found any other SQLite db clients that are independent of an IDE.

- [SQLite Manager - FireFox Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)
- [SQLite Manager - Project Page](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/)
- [SQLite Manager - Issue 602](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/issues/detail?id=602&can=1&q=WAL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you got any SQLite client with **seperated** sqlite3.dll you can easily swap that file with the latest one supporting WAL.

With that in mind you can find some more SQLite managers out there.

Comment: the interface of sqlite3.dll will not change. it's not a registered com-object. and all WAL-stuff is internal.